# Making re.sub print whole input along with its modifications

Tags: regex, python-3.x, parsing

All I need is to perform a parameter replacement in a config file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re

current_config = '''
    #USERNAME
    [name = foo]
    #-USERNAME
    #DATABASE
    [config = old]
    #-DATABASE
    #MORE_FIELDS
    [moresettings]
    #-MORE_FIELDS
    '''
new_config ='''
    #DATABASE
    [config = new]
    #-DATABASE
    '''

final = re.sub('#DATABASE}}(.*)#-#{{#-DATABASE}}', current_config, new_config)
print(final)
```

The regex itself works fine, the problem is that it prints out only the (correctly) modified part, ignoring the rest of the file:

```
dev-sandbox@workstation:~/PycharmProjects/test$ python3 test.py

    #DATABASE
    [config = new]
    #-DATABASE
```

What I want to achieve is the entire "current_config" variable including the new settings for the DATABASE block. I got it working with SED on shell, but I need this in python3.

Any help is much appreciated, the documentation for re.sub sugests it can't be done with it. Thank you!

Comment: Where is `#-#` in the target string?

Comment: Try `(?s)#DATABASE.*?#-DATABASE`

Comment: Thanks! There is no such "#-#" pattern in the target string. Honestly, I don't know what it does, it's part of a regex rule I was given but I assume it works fine since it is properly identifying "#DATABASE" and printing out the new parameters. I tried what you suggested but I'm afraid all it did was print the value for current_settings, it didn't perform the change ([config = old]). Here is the modified line: final = re.sub('(?si)#DATABASE.*?#-DATABASE', current_config, new_config)

Comment: You may have the parameters misplaced. The prototype is `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, max=0)` So, nothing is actually being replaced, the new string `final` is just assigned from `new_config`

Comment: Try `final = re.sub('(?s)#DATABASE.*?#-DATABASE\s*', new_config, current_config )` or even `final = re.sub('(?sm)^#DATABASE.*?#-DATABASE\s*', new_config, current_config )` for granularity.

Comment: You're right, those parameters were misplaced, sorry for that oversight. The first suggestion of your last comment solved this. Thank you very much for your assistance!